# Is there a way to find if path exists in a Directed acyclic graph in constant time (O(1))?

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-algorithm, directed-acyclic-graphs

I have some directed acyclic graph. I want to find if path exists between two vertices in `O(1)`.

Also, I want to add and remove edges between two vertices in `O(n^2)`.

I think, I need to store information, how many path exists between two nodes. But I don't come up full algorithm.

Comment: Regarding your first question you can just have a map which you precompute by adding a pair _A,B_ if _B_ is reachable from _A_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's assume that `f(i, j)` is the number of paths from `i` to `j` vertex. Initially(I assume that the graph is empty, if it is not the case you can add all edges using the add operation) `f(i, j) = 1` if `i = j` and `0` otherwise.

To add an edge from `a` to `b`, you can use the following procedure:

```
for i = 1 .. n
    for j = 1 .. n
        new_f(i, j) = f(i, j) + f(i, a) * f(b, j) //add the number of paths that contain a new edge
```

where `n` is the number of vertices.

Removing an edge can be done in a similar way:

```
for i = 1 .. n
        for j = 1 .. n
            new_f(i, j) = f(i, j) - f(i, a) * f(b, j) //subtract the number of paths that contian this edge
```

Removing/adding an edge obviously takes `O(n ^ 2)` time. A path from `a` to `b` exists if and only if `f(a, b) != 0`.

However, there is one issue with this solution: the number of paths can be very large(larger than a standard integer type can hold) and using arbitrary-precision arithmetic can increase time complexity. To avoid this issues, you can compute the number of paths modulo some large prime number(but small enough to fit into standard integer type) `p`. This solution can yield an incorrect result(the number of paths can be `0` modulo `p` even if it is actually non-zero), but the probability of a failure is low. To reduce it even more, you can compute `f` modulo several different prime numbers.

Comment: "modulo several different prime numbers" i.e., bignums with a convenient Chinese Remainder Theorem representation.

Answer (score -2):

Great place to read about this is "Algorithms, 4th ed." by Robert Sedgewick and Kevin Wayne.http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/home/ . They also present study course "Algorithms" at Coursera.org. It is free and there is material there to answer your question. Have a look.https://www.coursera.org/course/algs4partI

Comment: Downvote?! Very surprised! I don't see any sence in copypasting good study material, which you can get following links above, including much code in Java.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but link-only answers are considered bad since the links can break, leaving the answer completely worthless. It's OK to provide a link as part of an answer that summarizes the relevant information. (Note that link-only answers may also be flagged as spam. In this case it doesn't appear to be spam to me, unless you are somehow associated with either Princeton or coursera.